# Android adb permission error

Tags: android, linux, adb

I have installed the android SDK but I’m getting an error when using a hardware device, executing “./adb device$ I get this error:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

While if I execute “sudo ./adb device” there is no error:

```
List of devices attached 
HT019P80XXX device
```

Adb must work for all users (also when eclipse starts it) but It only works as root. The permissions of the related files are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72 2012-03-20 09:53 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ariadna ariadna 159620 2012-03-19 13:45 adb
```

I have googled and tried different solutions but none off then works on my Ubuntu, any idea?

Thank you

Comment: where you saved android SDK folder?

Comment: The path is /home/userFolder/SW/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools, could be related?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get it working by using this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", OWNER="kman",
GROUP="kman"
```

Comment: Makes sense - the udev rule needs to match the VID (and if given, PID) of the device you are attempting to connect - these can be found via lsusb or sometimes via dmseg.  0bb4 is a VID for HTC.

Answer (score 2):

Try finding your device and chown to your user:

In my case a Sony Ericsson:

```
lsusb | grep Sony
```

Output:

> "Bus **001** Device **018**: ID 0fce:6161 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications
>   AB"

then change the owner for that device:

```
sudo chown user:group /dev/bus/usb/001/018
```

Note 1: if you unplug the device/restart pc you will have to change owner again.

Note 2: you may need to start/restart adb server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

P.S. I also was unable to get it working with rules for udev. I really needed this because i am using eclipse that restarts adb without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

in the file 51-android.rules add to each row of "**owner**"

```
SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”0123″, SYMLINK+=”android_adb”, MODE=”0666″, OWNER=”your_user_name”
```

Then restart udev and adb

Comment: thank you but I does not work in my case, I have the same error introducing      SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4",SYMLINK+=”android_adb”, MODE=”0666″, OWNER=”ariadna, then I execute sudo service udev restart
 and ./adb devices (not as root). any other idea?

Comment: if you try switching OWNER with USER?

Comment: doing that works but I should not need root privilege to execute properly

Comment: sorry, but I don't see other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the appropriate udev line (assuming your device is an HTC) as follows:

SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”0bb4″, MODE=”0666″ GROUP="plugdev"

Then make sure you are in the group 'plugdev'.

BTW You are completely correct - you should absolutely not need to be root to start the adb server. Otherwise, to set up a multi-user environment with multiple android developers, you would need to give all developers root privileges or start the adb server during boot as root, neither of which are very sensible. If it is not possible on your system then it is a bug in udev.